# How to upload file on Google Drive using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I need help uploading the file to Google Drive.
Everything works fine but with an error during first trial.
During the debug at `request.upload` the cursor don't wait (wait for the file to upload) and skips to the next line `Dim responsefile As New Data.File` and I get nothing in `request.ResponseBody`.
After that I run the function cursor actually waits on `request.upload` and it uploads file successfully.
I don't know what is actually happening. I checked the data every time and it is the same.

```
Public Async Function UploadFile3(service As DriveService, FilePath As String) As Tasks.Task(Of Data.File)

        If service3.ApplicationName <> "netGDriveApi" Then CreateService()
            If IO.File.Exists(FilePath) Then
                Dim body As New Data.File()
                body.Name = IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath)
                body.Description = "BackUP file"
                body.MimeType = "application/octet-stream"
                'body.FileExtension = ".bak"



                '-------------------------------------------------UPLOAD FILE PROCESS-------------------------------------------------------------

                Dim byteArray As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
                Dim stream As New IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)
                Try
                    Dim request As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload = service.Files.Create(body, stream, body.MimeType)
                    Await request.UploadAsync() 'Cursor skips first time here and dont wait for response.
                    Dim responsefile As New Data.File 'Cursor waits from the above step to here till the file uploaded.


                    responsefile = request.ResponseBody

                    If IsNothing(responsefile) Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Try Again")
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show(responsefile.Id.ToString)
                    End If

                Catch e As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e.Message)
                    Return Nothing
                End Try

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("FILE DOES NOT EXISTS." + FilePath)
                Return Nothing
            End If
End Function
```

Comment: I get the feeling your life might be a lot simpler if you use WebClient.UploadFile or one of its async variations

Comment: Is this still happening if you don't use ```async/await``` function types?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Yes. I first tried without async/await.
Later tried with it. Both have sam e problem.

Comment: @CaiusJard I tried `request.Upload` but not working

Comment: @CaiusJard and how shall I upload the body settings like file mimetype and other things which Gdrive require while uploading a file if I use `web.client`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `Dim request As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload = service.Files.Create(body, stream, body.MimeType)`. Problem is here.
Thanks to @stevec to guide me the error.
The drive service is service3 and in the above line its just written `service.Files.Create`.
So the actual rectified answer is
`Dim request As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload = service3.Files.Create(body, stream, body.MimeType)`

Answer (score 2):

`request.UploadAsync()` returns a `Task(Of IUploadProgress)`. At the very least, you should be examining the result of this task. It might give you clues as to the cause of your problems.

For example, while debugging you could do something like the following:

```
Try
    Dim request As FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload = service.Files.Create(body, stream, body.MimeType)

    Dim Upload As IUploadProgress = Await request.UploadAsync() 'Cursor skips first time here and dont wait for response.

    If Upload.Status <> UploadStatus.Completed Then
        Dim ex As Exception = Upload.Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "UploadAsync Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Return Nothing
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(Upload.Status.ToString, "Upload Status:")
    End If

    Dim responsefile As New Data.File 'Cursor waits from the above step to here till the file uploaded.
    responsefile = request.ResponseBody
```

Always check what information methods return, and use that information as necessary in your production code.

Comment: Thanks stevec. Not the exact help but it leads me to the solution. My mistake is during creating `request` I set to `service.Files.Create` instead of `service3.Files.Create`. It works like charm now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please include that in a edit of this answer or post it as an answer itself so that other users with similar issues find the answer easily? Thanks !

Comment: Ya sure @MateoRandwolf